# How to reverse position in string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
a = "I'll buy paper,pen and beg"
print a[::-1]
```

The output:
    geb dna nep,repap yub ll'I

But I want output to be like this:
    g'eb dna nep r,epap yub llI

How can I do that?

Comment: In other words, you want to reverse the letters and space characters, but not punctuation?

Comment: Why is there supposed to be an apostrophe in both `g'eb` and `ll'I` in your examples?

Comment: Your desired output has two apostrophes.  Where did the other come from?

Comment: @kojiro i want reverse the string but maintain the index of the punctuation.

Comment: Sorry,just a typing error @LittleBobbyTables

Comment: Sorry,just a typing error @iCodez

Comment: +1 _Some_ effort has been put in (code has been given), and it is now fairly clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
targets = ".,'"
a = "I'll buy paper,pen and beg"
punct = [ (i, c) for i, c in enumerate (a) if c in targets]
nopunct = [c for c in a if c not in targets][::-1]
for i, c in punct: nopunct.insert (i, c)
b = ''.join (nopunct)
print (a)
print (b)
```

This prints

```
g'eb dna nepre,pap yub llI
I'll buy paper,pen and beg
```

Or changing targets to only `.,` it prints

```
geb dna neprep,ap yub ll'I
I'll buy paper,pen and beg
```

Comment: You could use `targets = string.punctuation` to get all punctuation

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good input. Let's leave this for OP to decide.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How to do that?

Comment: `import string`, then `target = string.punctuation`. `string.punctuation == '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~'`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe or just `from string import punctuation as target`?

Answer (score 6):

Take the reversed string and build a generator that only includes alpha characters. Then use that as a source of substitution for alpha characters going forward:

```
s = "I'll buy paper,pen and beg"
rev = (ch for ch in reversed(s) if ch.isalpha())
new = ''.join(next(rev) if ch.isalpha() else ch for ch in s)
# g'eb dna nepre,pap yub llI
```